# jQuery retrieve and group each select values in a form

Tags: jquery, arrays, select, each

Here is my HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
 <div>
    <h3>Goupe 1</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="options[1][type]">
            <option value="vector"></option>
            <option value="image"></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control multiple" name="options[1][size][]">
            <option value="800x600"></option>
            <option value="1024x768"></option>
            <option value="11280x1024"></option>
        </select>
    </div>
 </div>        

 <div class="validated">
    <h3>Goupe 2</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="options[2][type]">
            <option value="vector">Vector</option>
            <option value="image">Image</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control multiple" name="options[2][size][]">
            <option value="800x600">800x600</option>
            <option value="1024x768">1024x768</option>
            <option value="11280x1024">1280x1024</option>
        </select>
    </div>
 </div>
    ....
</form>
```

In jQuery I need to retrieve each select value for each group having a `validated` class and store this in a Javascript array.

- The number of groups can be different
- `options[n][type]` had single choice  (ex:vector)
- `options[n][size][]` had multiple choices (ex: `800x600`, `11280x1024`)

I am quite lost.

Comment: What format are you looking to put the values in to? An array, object, something else entirely? Also note that your HTML has syntax errors on each secondary `option` element onward.

Comment: javascript array, yes thanks, I fixed it, careless mistake.

Answer (score 0):

According your OP

> In jquery I need to retrieve each select values for each group having
>   a validated class and store this in javascript array.

You can use jquery [**.map()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

```js
var arr = $(".validated").find("select.form-control").map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
console.log(arr)//prints ["vector", "800x600"]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <div>
    <h3>Goupe 1</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" name="options[1][type]">
        <option value="vector"></option>
        <option value="image"></option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control multiple" name="options[1][size][]">
        <option value="800x600"></option>
        <option value="1024x768"></option>
        <option value="11280x1024"></option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="validated">
    <h3>Goupe 2</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" name="options[2][type]">
        <option value="vector">Vector</option>
        <option value="image">Image</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control multiple" name="options[2][size][]">
        <option value="800x600">800x600</option>
        <option value="1024x768">1024x768</option>
        <option value="11280x1024">1280x1024</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Of course this is just for demonstration. You can use it before you submit the form or whatever other action you wish.

Alternative you can return an array with objects to contain both selected value and select element name like:

```js
var arr = $(".validated").find("select.form-control").map(function () {
    return {
        name: $(this).attr("name"),
        value: $(this).val()
    }
}).get();
console.log(arr);//prints out an array with two objects
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
    <div>
         <h3>Goupe 1</h3>

        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" name="options[1][type]">
                <option value="vector"></option>
                <option value="image"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control multiple" name="options[1][size][]">
                <option value="800x600"></option>
                <option value="1024x768"></option>
                <option value="11280x1024"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="validated">
         <h3>Goupe 2</h3>

        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" name="options[2][type]">
                <option value="vector">Vector</option>
                <option value="image">Image</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control multiple" name="options[2][size][]">
                <option value="800x600">800x600</option>
                <option value="1024x768">1024x768</option>
                <option value="11280x1024">1280x1024</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image: output of the above code console.log]

**References**

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

[.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at below code. It uses a dummy HTML `form` to hold all the groups having `validated` class and then we are simply serializing that form.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var dummyForm = $("<form></form>");
  $(".validated").each(function(){
    dummyForm.append($(this).html());
  });  
    
  $("div.output").html(  JSON.stringify(dummyForm.serializeArray()));
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
 <div>
    <h3>Goupe 1</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="options[1][type]">
            <option value="vector">vector</option>
            <option value="image">image</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control multiple" name="options[1][size][]">
            <option value="800x600">800x600</option>
            <option value="1024x768">1024x768</option>
            <option value="11280x1024">11280x1024</option>
        </select>
    </div>
 </div>        

 <div class="validated">
    <h3>Goupe 2</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="options[2][type]">
            <option value="vector">Vector</option>
            <option value="image">Image</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control multiple" name="options[2][size][]">
            <option value="800x600">800x600</option>
            <option value="1024x768">1024x768</option>
            <option value="11280x1024">1280x1024</option>
        </select>
    </div>
 </div>

  
  <div class="validated">
    <h3>Goupe 2</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="options[3][type]">
            <option value="vector1">Vector1</option>
            <option value="image">Image</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control multiple" name="options[3][size][]">
            <option value="800x6001">800x6001</option>
            <option value="1024x768">1024x768</option>
            <option value="11280x1024">1280x1024</option>
        </select>
    </div>
 </div>
  
</form>
<div class="output">
</div>
```